# WebGL not working, even if already active

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

I have a web that requires WebGL active. I have done all the steps to get my WebGL active, even restarting Chrome. When I open the same web, it saysthat my WebGL is disabled. I have my hardware acceleration, WebGL 2.0 and override software rendering list active.

What could be the issue?

Comment: What GPU and operating system do you have?

Comment: my GPU is NVIDIA GeForce 210 as for the operating system is windows 7